# Where can I interactively play with jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I know there was website I once saw that permitted me to play interactively with JavaScript and jQuery. It had an IDE, a render pane and a result debugger thing too.

Does anyone know what it was called or anything like this?

Comment: You can also just start playing in the browser window.  Try pasting in `javascript:alert('hello');`

Comment: I'm not sure but, doesn't this sound like a question for stackoverflow community?

Comment: Relevant discussion on the meta site: http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/510/is-this-a-question-for-stackoverflow

Comment: Why is this closed or marked as too localized? It has 20 upvotes. The chosen answer 25 upvotes. It's one of the top 500 most upvoted questions on this site. It was agreed upon on meta.webapps as being on topic.

Comment: It may have been on topic in the past, but now questions asking to "recommend or find" a web app are off-topic. If this gets re-opened it will surely be re-closed with that reason.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Was it [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another option besides jsFiddle is [jsbin.com](http://jsbin.com/). You can even save your experiments under a public URL, so that others can view and edit your creation.

Comment: jsFiddle has a pastebin/share function itself.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Firefox, install [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), and then [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/).

Then on any webpage, open FireBug (bottom right), and enable the console (should be a little down arrow by "Console"). From here you'll see a button "jQuerify". Clicking it will inject jQuery into the current page.

You can type whatever jQuery-dependant JavaScript you want into the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FireFox you can use the FireBug Add-On.
If you are using IE, you can use the Developer toolbar (For IE7 or earlier you have to download and install it separately)

Press f12 on either platform to activate it. There is a Javascript console in lets you interactively enter java script commands.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a web app, but take a look at [jQueryPad](http://www.paulstovell.com/jquerypad). It's a downloadable application you can use to quickly build and test your script and markup.